# 'SequelizeDatabaseError: invalid input syntax for type json' when using json_set method

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have written this below sequelize expression to update `advertiserUrl` field in the Json which is stored in `order_data` column but I am getting

> SequelizeDatabaseError: invalid input syntax for type json

```
await campaigns.update({
    order_data: Sequelize.fn("JSONB_SET", Sequelize.col('order_data'), "{advertiser,advertiserUrl}", `${advertiserUrl}`)
  }, {
    where: {order_id: orderId}
  }
  )
```

I also tried this below query with sequelize this was also not working

```
const query = `UPDATE tbl_campaigns SET order_data =  jsonb_set(order_data::jsonb, '{advertiser,advertiserUrl}', '${advertiserUrl}', true) WHERE order_id = ${orderId}`
  await connection.query( query, { raw: true })
```

this query is working fine when I am running this in pgAdmin

Comment: Add   logging: console.log, to your update call and compare how it looks versus the raw query you have, that way you will find out what to modify in it

Comment: "this Query is working fine when I am running this in pgAdmin"  It certainly does not for me, provoking a syntax error at `${orderId}`.  Please show the actual query which worked fine.